# How to encode/decode Google's protocol buffer extensions in Erlang?

Tags: erlang, protocol-buffers

I'm using [basho's erlang protocol buffer](https://github.com/basho/erlang_protobuffs)

There's a usr.proto:

```
message Msg {
  required int32 id = 1;
  extensions 100 to max;
}
message Usr {
  extend Msg { optional Usr msg = 1000; }
  required int64 id = 1;
}
```

I can encode Usr:

```
UsrBin = usr_pb:encode_usr(#usr{id = 1})
```

and decode Usr:

```
UsrMsg = usr_pb:decode_usr(list_to_binary(UsrBin))
```

Here's the problem:
Now I want to encode Msg, so I create a dict:

```
Extensions = dict:append(1000, UsrMsg, dict:new())
```

then I encode Msg:

```
MsgBin = usr_pb:encode_msg(#msg{id = 1, '$extensions' = Extensions})
```

and decode Msg:

```
MsgMsg = usr_pb:decode_msg(list_to_binary(MsgBin))
```

However, I can't get the extensions:

```
msg_pb:get_extension(MsgMsg, 1000)(this returned "undefined")
```

What was wrong? I thought I was coding it the wrong way, plz help me out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I dived into the usr_pb.erl that was generated by protobuffs_compile:generate/1, I thought it's a bug in the protobuffs library.

It didn't generate the right functions for the extensions if the extensions definition were nested(i.e. the extensions were defined inside the message definition). Now if I rewrite the proto file like this:

```
message Msg {
  required int32 id = 1;
  extensions 100 to max;
}

message Usr {
  required int64 id = 1;
}

extend Msg {
  optional Usr msg = 1000;
}
```

everything goes fine.

And the APIs that corresponding to extensions are clear:

```
usr_pb:set_extension(#msg{id = 1, '$extensions' = dict:new()}, msg, UsrMsg)

{ok, Extension} = usr_pb:get_extension(MsgDecoded, msg),
```